# Why is this test on the total variation of a process wrong?

Tags: real-analysis, total-variation

By the mean value theorem
$$|f(t_i)-f(t_{i-1})|=f'(c)(t_{j}-t_{j-1})$$

and Let the total variation be
$$sup\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}|f_{t}-f_{t-1}|$$

Now.Taking norm of the partition
$$\left\|∏\right\| = max[(t_{j}-t_{j-1}):i=1,2....(n)]$$
By definition (it's intuitive) that

$$\left\|∏\right\|\ge(t_{j}-t_{j-1})$$
Therefore, replacing and / or combining with the mean value theorem.

$$\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}f'(c)\left\|∏\right\|\ge\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}f'(c)(t_{j}-t_{j-1})$$

Now. Taking the left part and taking limit on the maximum partition tending to zero.
$$lim_{∏\rightarrow0}\left\|∏\right\|\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}f'(c) = 0$$

I know that the answer must not be zero, but a definite integral over the considered interval. I am intrigued to know why this test is correct for quadratic variation, but not for total variation.

Comment: $c$ depnds on the partition  and the number of terms is also varying so you cannot say that $$lim_{∏\rightarrow0}\left\|∏\right\|\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}f'(c) = 0$$

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy
Why do you say that "you cannot say that the expression tends to zero"? I don't really understand that concept. Thanks.

Comment: Consider the simpler variant $\sum_{i=1}^n(1/n)=1$. The same is the case of your sum. As the norm tends to $0$ the number of terms in the sum tends to infinity. So we can't say without further analysis that the sum tends to zero. In fact a definite integral is defined as a limit of such sums and it is not necessarily zero.

Comment: @Paramanand Singh
Hello.
1) I did not understand the reference to
$$\sum_{j=1}^{n}(1/n)=1$$

2) If the norm tends to zero the sum of terms would become infinite, that is correct. But that infinite sum would not be equal to zero when replacing the value of || ∏ || by the value it tends to, which is zero (0). That is to say:

$$[\left\|∏\right\|f'(c_1)] +  [\left\|∏\right\|f'(c_2)] + [\left\|∏\right\|f'(c_3)]... $$
Replacing ||∏|| = 0:
$$\underbrace{[0*(f'(c_1)]}_{0} +  \underbrace{[0*(f'(c_2))]}_{0} + \underbrace{[0*(f'(c_3)]}_{0}
... = 0$$

Grateful for your answer

Answer (score 1):

This could be a comment but is too long.

There seems to be at least four errors in your analysis.  First, your use of the mean value theorem should be without the modulus signs or you should include modulus signs on the derivative as well.  Second, when deriving the inequality $$\sum_{j\geqslant 1} f'(c_j)\lVert \Pi \rVert \geqslant \sum_{j\geqslant 1} f'(c_j)(t_j - t_{j-1})$$ you seem to be assuming each $f'(c_j)$ is positive.  These error would be avoided if you used $\lvert f'(c_j)\rvert$ throughout. Third, in your notation the value $c$ depends on the interval so you should write it in a way that makes clear each occurrence of $c$ in the sum is different, e.g. by writing $c_j$.

But fourth, and most significantly, as observed in comments, when $\lVert \Pi \rVert \to 0$, $n \to \infty$ and so you have a longer and longer sum of (possibly) smaller and smaller terms.  However that does not guarantee convergence to zero.  You need only consider $f(x) = x$ to obtain a counter example, where the right hand side of your inequality is always exactly equal the length of the interval and the left side always something greater, so neither side has limit zero.